# not able to pick value from webpage and get it into excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am new to VBA,
I want some data from webpage into excel sheet..
I have written code for visiting the web page, input value and clicking on submit button.
On clicking submit button, next webpage comes.. I want the emailID from that webpage to my excel sheet.. Please help

the code i have written is as follows:

```
Sub emailforcform()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://registration.apct.gov.in/ctdportal/Search/EMailSearch.aspx"
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to connect"
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.document
ie.document.all("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TxtTin").Value = "28740213505"
ie.document.all("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButGet").Click
Range("c4").Value = ie.document.all("ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePnl").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me...

```
Sub test()
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "https://registration.apct.gov.in/ctdportal/Search/EMailSearch.aspx"

    Application.StatusBar = "Trying to connect"

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
          DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.Document.all("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TxtTin").Value = "28740213505"
    ie.Document.all("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButGet").Click

    Application.StatusBar = "Preparing to retrieve the email ID"

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
          DoEvents
    Loop

    Range("c4").Value = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(7).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext
end sub
```

Comment: I forgot to put a loop in between the line where you click the button and the line where we capture the e-mail ID.  We need the loop to give the new page time to load.  See my updated code.